# How to use Global Commands in Microsoft Bot Framework?

Tags: c#, botframework

I have read somewhere that we can use `IScorable.cs` to implement globally available commands e.g. type "settings" anywhere in chat flow to open settings dialog. But there seems to be no documentation on how to use it.

Please help.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are right, implementing `IScorable.cs` is the way to go if you want to have global commands in BotFramework.

Having an IScorable it's basically a two steps procedure:

1. Write your IScorable
2. Register your IScorable in the BotFramework's Autofac container

BotFramework will go through all the `IScorables` first to see if any of them "wins" (a.k.a. if they will be doing something or not) and if no one handle the message; then it will continue dispatching the message to the dialogs.

Regarding how to write your `IScorable`, the best thing is to look into some examples:

- [Settings scorable](https://github.com/Microsoft/BotBuilder-Samples/blob/4801b8736288a2956e5aa46c950a3940d9dcc38a/CSharp/demo-ContosoFlowers/ContosoFlowers/Dialogs/SettingsScorable.cs) (from [ContosoFlowers sample](https://github.com/Microsoft/BotBuilder-Samples/tree/master/CSharp/demo-ContosoFlowers/ContosoFlowers)). It launches a new dialog when the a "settings" message is sent.
- [DeleteProfile scorable](https://github.com/Microsoft/BotBuilder/blob/8f0d6bbc1ef0fcef99b04560391384aba8fcde15/CSharp/Library/Microsoft.Bot.Builder/Dialogs/DeleteProfileScorable.cs) (coming in the BotFramework). It deletes the PrivateConversationData and UserData bags and also reset the stack when a "/deleteprofile" message is sent.
- [Alarm scorable](https://github.com/Microsoft/BotBuilder/blob/master/CSharp/Samples/AlarmBot/Models/AlarmScorable.cs) (from the [AlarmsBot](https://github.com/Microsoft/BotBuilder/blob/master/CSharp/Samples/AlarmBot/) sample). It calls a service to perform an operation if the message matches to any of the predefined verbs.

Regarding how to register the `IScorable`, I would recommend you doing something like the following in the `Global.asax.cs`, `Application_Start` method:

```
var builder = new ContainerBuilder();

builder.RegisterType<SettingsScorable>()
    .As<IScorable<IActivity, double>>()
    .InstancePerLifetimeScope();

builder.Update(Conversation.Container);
```

That shows how the `SettingsScorable` of the ContosoFlowers is being registered in the `Autofac` container.

Comment: What if I am not using the Autofac container or not using IoC at all? In Node.js there is a simpler way to achieve this but not in C# SDK.

Comment: If you are using the C# BotBuilder NuGet package, you are always using Autofac :), because behind of the scenes the BotFramework uses it. The registration that you need to do is on the BotFramework's Autofac container; you won't need to use it to resolve your components but the IScorable needs to be register there

Comment: Maybe I'm a philistine, but I also find the IScorable architecture abstruse. It's like it was designed by a developer trying to show off how convoluted he/she could make it. Why not at least a simpler version with two methods to implement: a 'bool If(IActivity incomingActivity)' and 'void DoStuffIfYes(...)'?